# Invalid block tag in django

Tags: django

I've done pretty much everything in my knowledge to solve this, but I guess I've gone wrong somewhere as I'm still a beginner, so I'd like someone to kindly help me out with this and also **I've added the error message at the bottom, including the code**

**error**

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /
Invalid block tag on line 9: 'static'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.1.6
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Invalid block tag on line 9: 'static'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
Exception Location: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py, line 531, in invalid_block_tag
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.1
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Django\\ecommerce',
 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 09 Apr 2021 00:16:08 +0000
```

**setting**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

**css/main.css**

```
body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

**store/main.html**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ecommerce</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Navbar</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}

        {% endblock content %}
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**store**

```
{% extends 'store/main.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
    <h3>Store</h3>
{% endblock content %}
```

**store/urls.py** -- *This is the app*

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.store,name="store"),
    path('cart/',views.cart,name="cart"),
    path('checkout/',views.checkout,name="checkout"),
]
```

**ecom/urls.py**

```
    from django.contrib import admin

    from django.urls import path,include
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('', include('store.urls')),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add static template tag `{% load static %}`
in main.html

> In your templates, use the static template tag to build the URL for
> the given relative path using the configured STATICFILES_STORAGE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ecommerce</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Navbar</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}

        {% endblock content %}
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I had no idea about that